# invalid class typecast in intraweb

Tags: delphi, casting, intraweb

I'm porting an old application from delphi7 to delphi xe8
and from intraweb 8 to intraweb XIV

My app was subdivided in a main program and a number of child packages
and it worked perfectly with the old components.

With theese new components, I now get an exception trying to generate and return a page to the server controller, creating such a page from a child package.
If instead I generate the page from the main app, it works.

In the procedure TIWServerController.IWServerControllerBaseGetMainForm
I call a procedure of a my component (packman) that tries to obtain a main window from a child package.
this is the servercontroller function

```
procedure TIWServerController.IWServerControllerBaseGetMainForm(var vMainForm : TIWBaseForm);
begin
  VMainForm := PackMan.MainLoginForm(webApplication);
end;
```

and this is the packman function:

```
function  tPackMan.MainLoginForm (aOwner:tComponent) : tIwAppForm;
var    Proc  : tGetMainFormProc;
begin
  @Proc  := GetProcAddress (LoginPkg,'MainForm');
  Result := Proc(aOwner);
end;
```

this is the definition of the procedural type:

```
  tGetMainFormProc = function (aOwner:tComponent): tIwAppForm;
```

and this is the MainForm procedure, in the child package (packlogin).
Initially I tried to create the original form, full of components,
after that I've removed all components from original form, without success, 
and finally I tried to construct an empty form, as shown in this sample:

```
function MainForm (aOwner:tComponent): tIWAppForm;
begin
  Result := tIWAppForm.Create(aOwner);
end;
exports MainForm;
```

I've traced the program behaviour using several Outputdebugstring messages (here not shown) and I've come to the following conclusion:

1) the Mainform procedure, in the package, seems to return a valid tIwAppform

2) this Object is correctly returned to the IWServerControllerBaseGetMainForm procedure
and the variable VMainForm is correctly assigned.

3) if I inspect the classname property of this variable, I see it has the value "tIWAppform".

The exception seems to be generated at the procedure return.
I've interceped it in the procedure IWServerControllerBaseException
with the following code :

```
procedure TIWServerController.IWServerControllerBaseException(
  AApplication: TIWApplication; AException: Exception;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
    Dump ('UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION ' + AException.message);
    Handled := true;
end;
```

What am I missing ?

Any suggestion ?

Regards.

Maurizio.

Comment: Looks awfully like you are passing objects across module boundaries in an illegal manner. That `exports` is the tell tale sign.

Comment: Can you post the whole exception message ? If possible you should post the StackTrace too ..

Comment: This sounds like maybe the modules are not compiled with Runtime Packages enabled, so RTTI across module boundaries is not matching as expected.

Comment: this is a partial stack trace : 
Unexpected exception Invalid class typecast
Stacktrace : 
(00367D09){SeleMgr.exe } [00768D09] Unknown function at TMethodImplementationIntercept + $2FCE15 
(00005DDE){SeleMgr.exe } [00406DDE] 
(00007B73){SeleMgr.exe } [00408B73] 
(00367D09){SeleMgr.exe } [00768D09] Unknown function at TMethodImplementationIntercept + $2FCE15 
(00369A06){SeleMgr.exe } [0076AA06] Unknown function at TMethodImplementationIntercept + $2FEB12 
(000422DA){SeleMgr.exe } [004432DA] 
there are a lot more similar rows...

Comment: OK, it seems it was the combination of Runtime packages and RTTI.
I had to compile the app with runtime packages, and enable RTTI in the packages. Now it seems to work.
Thanks. Maurizio.